# When using rand() to generate numbers how can I verify that 'if' and 'else' statements guarantee me a correct answer?

Tags: ruby, random

I am attempting an exercise from a book that doesn't show any example code for a correct answer, so I'm not sure where I may have strayed. I've written what I felt was a good bit of code, but now I'm not sure if my code will return my statement for a correct guess.

The code:

```
prng = rand(10)

puts "What's your guess (1-9)?"

user_guess = gets.chomp

if user_guess == prng
    puts "You guessed correctly!"
else
    puts "Try again!"
end
```

I feel as though my `if` statement might be the issue here, because when I run the code it always returns my `else` statement. I've also tried narrowing the range of numbers so that my guess is more likely correct and I still didn't trigger the `if` statement's `puts`.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rand(10)` returns an integer.  `gets` returns a string.  A string (in ruby) is never equal to an integer.

You need to either convert your input to an integer (`gets.chomp.to_i`) or your integer to a string: (`rand(10).to_s`) before you compare them.

**Edit**: If you need to debug further, you should check what the values actually are:

```
puts "The answer was #{prng.inspect} and you guessed #{user_guess.inspect}"
```

Comment: `to_s` should be underscored, not a dash

Comment: Thanks for your response, John. I changed the 'gets.chomp' to 'gets.chomp.to_i' and narrowed the range again, but I seem to be at the same point, just getting the 'else's return statement.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `rand(10)` returns values between 0-9, not 1-10.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't realize I could use something like `.inspect`. Thanks, it's working now!